# 301 Redirect is not working in ASP

Tags: redirect, asp-classic

I have looked through all the asp redirects and they all say the same thing. I'm trying to redirect single .asp pages to new url. Here is the code I keep seeing and have tried placing at the beginning of the pages in question multiple times:

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader ( "Location","http://www.new-location.com" )
%>
```

It does not seem to work. It looks like typical .asp page swith the `<@ Language=VBScript %>`
 at the top followed by html code. Is there another way to redirect single .asp pages?

Answer (score 8):

I think that the parentheses are the trouble here

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.new-location.com"
%>
```

Comment: +1. It seems like there's `On Error Resume Next` in somewhere above. Otherwise, should an error occur because of the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

`<%@ language="VBScript" %>
<% 
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader ( "Location","http://www.new-location.com" ) 
%>`

Comment: What's the difference between this and the code in the question?

Comment: 1: There's a space between <%@ and language. 2: Double quotes surround VBScript in the language= statement. There is an error though... the parens need to go. I'm voting for Eduardo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late, but if you have HTML following the redirect you will need to use Response.End():

```
<%@ language="VBScript" %>
<% 
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader ( "Location","http://www.new-location.com" ) 
Response.End()
%>
```